# AWS Lambda spin up EC2 and triggers user data script

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, boto3

I need to spin up an instance using Lambda on S3 trigger. Lambda has to spin up an EC2 and trigger a user data script.

I have an aws cli something like `aws —region use-east-1 s3 cp s3://mybucket/test.txt /file/`

Looking for python boto3 implementation.Since lambda is new to me, can someone share if its doable?

One way is Lambda runs CFT and `UserData` is part of CFT, but think there should be an easier way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include UserData parameter in your Boto3 function.

You should use a code like that:

```
ec2.create_instances(
   ImageId='<ami-image-id>',
   InstanceType='t1.micro',
   UserData='string',
   ....
```

If you don't need to create, but just run, you should use:

```
 ec2.client.run_instances(
    ...
    UserData='string',
    ...
```

You can see all arguments that create_instance and run_instances support in:

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Subnet.create_instances

Comment: Create and Run do the same thing, but Run is on a client object and Create is on an EC2 object.